# VSCode complaining that installed .NET Desktop Runtime does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, configuration

I am using vscode to write C# scripts for Unity.  When starting up vscode, it brings up a popup box with the title "Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.exe" and the error message reads:

```
You must install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application.

Architecture: x64
App host version: 6.0.16

Would you like to download it now?

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
```

With yes and no buttons at the bottom to presumable download the runtime, which does not work.

I have downloaded and installed the runtime that it asks for.  In the terminal I run `dotnet --info` and it lists the requested runtime as well as 7.0.9 which is the version of .NET I originally installed.  Not quite sure why it started asking for this version and how do I get it to run with just 7.0.9?

I have tried removing and reinstalling the desktop runtime, but still get the same error.  I also looked around the install for .NET and did not find the desktop runtime. I read that .NET 7 only looks in one location. Can I change its install location for the 6.0.16 install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who might find this issue, I solved it by uninstalling .NET extensions from vscode and then uninstalling .NET (using the original installer).  Also, if using Unity, I deleted the csproj files from my project.  Then reinstalled every back in reverse order.
No idea how I got this issue or if there was a more simple solution.

Comment: Hi mgogolin, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)